# AUR Package Problems

Tags: command-line, package-management, git

I don't know whether this is the best place to ask but, I've recently installed xubuntu and I'm trying to make my desktop look like macOS.

I'm following a tutorial where they download AUR packages, how do I access this and install packages? I have tried to download them through the git clone, however, when I enter `makepkg -si`, it comes up with

> makepkg - command not found

I then tried to download `base-devel`, but it then says

> pacman - command not found

All I want to do is download the packages. Is it really that hard?
I do apologize as I don't know anything, but I'm trying to learn.

Comment: AUR means "Arch User Repository", which is a bit different from how Debian-based systems handle packages 

Comment: Sounds as if your following a guide for Arch Linux or Manjaro.

Comment: Please share a link to the tutorial with exact AUR packagenames / PKGFILEs. We can try to adapt Arch solution for Ubuntu.

Answer (score 2):

There are a lot of different package formats in the Linux world. You need to use the one that is suitable for the kind of Linux you are using. To name just the most popular ones:

- DEB for Debian (hence the name) and Ubuntu with all its flavours, using the dpkg and the higher-level apt package managers
- RPM (Red Hat Package Manager) for Red Hat / Fedora, SUSE, Mandriva and more
- AUR for Arch Linux and Manjaro, using the PacMan package manager

On Ubuntu, you need DEB packages. For very exceptional cases and if you are an advanced user, you can also install some others (e.g. RPM) if you know what you are doing, but for a novice Ubuntu user, I would not recommend that. Stick with DEB and use the`apt` command or the graphical `synaptic`.

So, try to find instructions for that program how to build DEB packages. Or check if maybe somebody already did that and provides those packages as a PPA. Or maybe it's already in the official Ubuntu repositories.

Comment: The AUR is a repository not a format. The AUR contains a large collection of scripts that build packages from scratch. A package, once built is installed by pacman. Arch also has several repository’s containing prebuilt packages that can be installed with pacman -S packagename which is not unlike an apt install packagename command.

Answer (score 1):

You are using xubuntu whic means ubuntu based distribution, meanwhile AUR is a community-driven repository for Arch​-based linux distributions.
Below are the things you can do as alternative:

1. PPA.
   PPA (Personal Package Archives) is software repositories designed
   for Ubuntu based users. Similar to AUR, PPA is also maintained by
   user. You can install third party software or package which is not
   available in official repository easily by adding particular PPA
   repository in your sources.list. PPA also very recomended for user
   who wants something latest. Sometimes a package you want is
   available from official repository but the package is outdated, so
   PPA is the right choice. You can explore more about PPA and how to
   use it from google :)
2. Build package manually.
   Most of AUR package are github downstream. It means the source of
   origianl package are from github. So what you can do is, visit the
   AUR package url then find Upstream URL or source in Package Details
   section, then you can follow the link that will direct you to the
   original source (github or any else). You can follow the
   installation guide from the original source which is more general
   for any linux distribution.